# Label text for default option of three-state radio button group

Tags: forms, radio-buttons

We have a table with radio button filters and are struggling with logical wording for the labels, or specifically the label for the default option.

The tables are of people, and each person could belong to multiple teams. We have radios to filter by people in each team, as well as people *not* in them. The default state is just showing everyone.

We have 4-5 teams, each with similar radio groups as below. Two for example:

```
BLUE TEAM                         RED TEAM

(*)N/A   ()Only   ()None          (*)N/A   ()Only   ()None
```

"Only" and "None" should hopefully be obvious, but definitely open to other suggestions on those.

We are currently using "N/A" as the default option which will show people in or not in the team. Is there a better label for that? We've experimented with "All" or "Any", but either of those *could* be understood as "all of Blue Team", or "any person in Blue Team". That being said, "N/A" doesn't feel great either.

Also, horizontal real estate prevents us having very long descriptive labels like, "Users on and off Blue Team".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The meaning of Only, None and N/a are not that clear to me. But I believe you want something like this:

```
In the BLUE TEAM?                 In the RED TEAM?

( ) Only   ( ) No   (*) Maybe     ( ) Only   ( ) No   (*) Maybe
```

But it would look nicer if you can claim more vertical space:

| Available in | No | Maybe | Only |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BLUE TEAM | ( ) | (*) | ( ) |
| RED TEAM | ( ) | (*) | ( ) |

"Exclusively" is a better word for "Only" in my opinion, but it depends on the target audience which one is better understood.

Comment: This is great wording and what I was looking for. There is no ambiguity here. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, this approach is a bit convoluted, which affects the labels (**N/A** is really confusing, as it means *"not available "*).

Instead, I would suggest that you flip your logic and instead of filtering by two different variables (the teams), filter by only one variable (the players). So you can proceed something like this:

```
() Blue team     () Red team     () Both     () None
```

I am not sure if you need the last variable, but I am including it as an example of how easy it would be to add more filter variables.

Edit: based on your new information, the aproach still works. Check below:

[image]

I'm using an IPhone 8 with a width of 375px, so you can see that it fits on small areas. Also take a look at the second option: by using checkboxes you can select all applicable items in any combination, the last checkbox is labeled "none" and serves as a reset (so, selecting it will deselect all other options)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I’m all for making it less convoluted, but I don’t think this solution would work because we actually have four teams. I only added two for illustration, but now realize that was key info to add. Apologies for that, and I will update my question.

Comment: Appreciate the edit @Devin. In many cases that would do the trick, but in this case it would not because of the three required states. 

For example, a user sometimes needs to show players ONLY Red team users who are NOT on the Green team, but could still be on the Orange/Red/Blue teams. It's a strange table with strange data!

Comment: that's why I used teh second version with checkboxes, to enable exactly what you say. Remember checkboxes allow multiple selections, while radio input allows for only one selection